# How to retrieve this doc using java

Tags: java, json, mongodb, rest

can anybody help me out i retrieving this type of json body documents from mongodb

```
{
"question":"what is your color?",
"choices":[{"option":"yello"},{"option":"blue"},{"option":"green"}],
"creation-date":"2014-04-13",
"expiry date":"2014-04-14"
}
```

Here is the code i am writing

```
   public Poll getPollById(String id) {
    try{
    mongoClient=new MongoClient("NavDeep",27017);
    db=mongoClient.getDB("sms-voting");
    collection=db.getCollection("pollsCollection");
    }catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Poll poll=new Poll();
    Choice c=new Choice();
    List<Choice> choice=new ArrayList<Choice>(); 
    DBObject object=collection.findOne(new BasicDBObject("pollid",id));
    String pollID=(String)object.get("pollid");
    String question=(String)object.get("question");
    //how should i retrive choices??
    BasicDBList choices=(BasicDBList) object.get("choices");


    for(int i=0;i<choices.size();i++){
    BasicDBObject choicesObj = (BasicDBObject) choices.get(i);
    String opt=choicesObj.getString("option");
    long count=choicesObj.getLong("count");
    c.setOption(opt);
    c.setCount(count);
    choice.add(c);

    }
    Date creation_date=(Date)object.get("creation date");
    Date expiry_date=(Date)object.get("expiry date");

    poll.setId(pollID);
    poll.setQuestion(question);
    poll.setChoices(choice);
    poll.setStart(creation_date);
    poll.setEnd(expiry_date);
    mongoClient.close();
    return poll;
    }
```

These are the classes for Poll and Choice class
    package edu.sjsu.cmpe.voting.api;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include;
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;

import edu.sjsu.cmpe.voting.api.Choice;

public class Poll {


@JsonProperty("pollid")
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_DEFAULT)
private String id;
@JsonProperty("question")
private String question;

@Valid
@JsonProperty("choices")
private ArrayList<Choice> choices;

@JsonProperty("creation date")
private Date start;

@JsonProperty("expiry date")
private Date end;   

public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
/**
 * @return the question
 */
public String getQuestion() {
    return question;
}
/**
 * @param question the question to set
 */
public void setQuestion(String question) {
    this.question = question;
}

public ArrayList<Choice> getChoices() {
    return choices;
}
public void setChoices(ArrayList<Choice> choices) {

    this.choices=choices;
}

public Date getStart() {
    return start;
}
public void setStart(Date start) {
    this.start = start;
}
public Date getEnd() {
    return end;
}
public void setEnd(Date end) {
    this.end = end;
}
```

}

where Choice is another class which has option and count as its fields.

I am getting an exception that `BasicDBobject(get("choices")) cnanot be converted into BasicDBList`

What to do??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error means that for the document you are retrieving, the "choices" field is an object and not an array. So please use the mongo shell and verify that for the id that you're querying on the data is correct as you expect.

Comment: true...Options field was not getting inserted into mongo db.how do i insert the array of choices in to mongo db using java??

Comment: Something like this: `DBObject poll = new BasicDBObject(); BasicDBList choices = new BasicDBList(); poll.put("choices", choices); DBObject choice1 = new BasicDBObject(); choice1.put("option", "yellow"); choices.add(choice1); collection.save(poll);`

Comment: Thanks.But i should not hard code the values.I have setter and getter methods for Poll and choice class.

Comment: If you want to use a POJO, you should probably look at [Morphia](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia) then, or for a simple case look at ReflectionDBObject.